# Transforming a dataframe from wide to long using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to transform my database from a wide format to a long format so that I can make a plot where there are the years in the x axis and the shares in the y axis. I would like to draw a line for each family because the goal is to see the gap between the two 2034 values.

This is what my dataframe currently looks like:
[image: Current Dataframe]

And this is my desired output (I would call the x-axis "Year" and the y-axis "Share")
[image: Desired output]

I have already tried using the "gather" option of "dplyr" using:

```
gather(CPS_fam.long, Year, Share, 2:5)
```

but I optain the years duplicated instead of the Family Name.

I cannot provide the data but any suggestion using a sample dataframe would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please share your data using `dput` instead of screenshots. Also can you show what output do you get with `tidyr::gather(CPS_fam.long, Year, Share, 2:5)` or `tidyr::gather(CPS_fam.long, Year, Share, -Fam_Name)`. Both of them should give you the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you already got the right code but simply have to `arrange` the resulting data frame by `Fam_Name`.

Let me reproduce your problem:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble("Fam_Name" = c("Architecture", "Arts", "Business"), "2002" = c(0.134, 0.116, 0.399), "2018" = c(0.161, 0.089, 0.06))

df %>% gather(., key = Year, value = Shares, c("2002", "2018"))

#  Fam_Name     Year  Shares
#  <chr>        <chr>  <dbl>
#1 Architecture 2002   0.134
#2 Arts         2002   0.116
#3 Business     2002   0.399
#4 Architecture 2018   0.161
#5 Arts         2018   0.089
#6 Business     2018   0.06
```

Now, with `arrange` as last part of the pipe:

```
df %>% gather(., key = Year, value = Shares, c("2002", "2018")) %>% arrange(Fam_Name)

#  Fam_Name     Year  Shares
#  <chr>        <chr>  <dbl>
#1 Architecture 2002   0.134
#2 Architecture 2018   0.161
#3 Arts         2002   0.116
#4 Arts         2018   0.089
#5 Business     2002   0.399
#6 Business     2018   0.06
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! Thank you very much